# #py how to make telegram bot send notification when 10 messages are uploaded

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, message

I'm a manager of the tg group channel and I want to let group members be reminded that reply service is unavailable during the midnight. I want to send this notification message when more than 10 messages are uploaded during the midnight.

How can I make this condition on the code using python

Please give any hints
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but it should work.

I used the message handler for text content and a global variable to count the number of messages sent before a certain hour (06:00hs in this example). I used python's datetime library to get the current hour of the machine where the bot is running. If that number is lower than 6 (i.e. current time is between 00hs and 06hs), then I increment the counter. If the counter gets to 10, I send the message and reset it.

```
import telebot
import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot(<TOKEN>)
        
msg_count = 0
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_command_adminwindow(message):
    global msg_count
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if (current_time < 6):
        msg_count = msg_count + 1
        if (msg_count == 10):
            msg_count = 0
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                            text="Reply service is unavailable during the midnight",
                            parse_mode='HTML')
    else:
        msg_count = 0


bot.infinity_polling()
```

You shouldn't have problems with the global variable as long as you use your bot on a single group, since it will be shared between any chats the bot is in.
I also decided to reset the counter whenever a message is sent on time, so that we don't keep an old counter. This could be solved in a more efficient way, though.

Also, remember to disable the Group Privacy setting on your bot using @botfather, so that your bot can handle messages from a group.